# Gradle - A problems occurred evaluating root project '*'. > Could not find method compile() for arguments [*] on root project '*'

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Eclipse Luna to develop my Android app. I don't have any idea why the error message keep showing again and again. I got this error message after fill up dependencies in `build.gradle` and run `gradle build` in my terminal.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.8@aar'
}
```

Error message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/MNurdin/Documents/Github/Swipecards/example/src/main/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'main'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:X.X.X@aar] on root project 'main'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.34 secs
```

Project: https://github.com/datomnurdin/Swipecards

Comment: Just change to `compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.8@aar'`

Comment: show more code about your build.gradle?

Comment: thats all so far. I'm not familiar with gradle thing.

Comment: Why are you using @aar library?  Did you import a library project as a module?

Comment: i'm not really sure about that sir.

Answer (score 2):

change to this:

```
compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.8'
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the error when I tried using gradle 2.6 to build a project that was built using gradle 2.3. Make sure the versions are the same.

Comment: Same was for me. Version was lower then in the project. 
I've used sdk man for handling it.

Answer (score 1):

`compile` is a [dependency configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_dependency_configurations.html#sub:inheriting_dependencies_from_other_configurations) that comes [from the Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management).

The Android Gradle plugin applies the Java plugin under the covers. I do not see the Android plugin *applied* in your Gradle script. I think you may be missing a [module-level build configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#module-level) that applies the Android Gradle plugin which would add `dependencies.compile(...)` to the DSL.

Answer (score 0):

The compile task is defined by the java plugin. However, as you do not include it in your root project it does not exist there so gradle does not know how to handle it.
In order to resolve it you can either:

1. Apply the java plugin to your root project. The downside of this approach would be that this plugin will be included automatically in all your sub project that in somecases may be undesired, and also by default there will be an empty jar created for this project.
2. Define a dummy empty compile task yourself so gradle will be happy.